# Why the compiler issues no error for erroneous extern declaration?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

On file1 I've defined the variable args as:

```
CLA args;
```

On file2 I've declared it as:

```
extern CLA* args;
```

The program would compile with both gcc and clang with no errors, and no errors would appear on valgrind either. There was a problem though: On file2 the function *fprintf(args->output, ...)* would not print anything. Why there were no errors issued?

Comment: Try to imagine a sensible compiler error to issue in this case. I don't think you can do it. I have a file3 on my machine that declares `args` as an `int`. Should your compiler warn about that?

Comment: This is why you need a header to declare the variable (if you really must use a global variable), and the header is then included by both source files, and acts as the referee — it will cause the compiler to reject the erroneous file.  See [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The program would compile with both gcc and clang with no errors

Because each C file is compiled independently. When the resultant object files are linked, the linker has only symbol names. It does not know the *types* associated with those symbols.

This is one of the reasons<sup>1</sup> that C++ uses *name mangling*: the type of the symbol is embedded in its name, so if there is a mismatch, link failure will occur.

This is why you either don't use globals, or you declare them in header files, and include that header file everywhere you reference said global, *including the unit that defines it*.

There is never a reason for `extern` to show up in a `.c` file; only in a `.h` file.

> and no errors would appear on valgrind either.

We haven't seen your source code so we can't know how you might be using said variable incorrectly in such a way that valgrind would detect it.

---

<sup>1 - The other, primary reason is to support overloaded functions.</sup>

Comment: Do C++ global variables get name mangled?  GCC (`g++`) 7.2.0 on a Mac compiles `int gobbledygook = 13;` to an object file defining `0000000000000000 D _gobbledygook` according to `nm`.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following instead:

Create a header file, let's call it `globals.h`. It should look similar to this:

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

/* include whatever you need, declare the CLA type */

extern CLA *args;

/* define/declare/etc. whatever you need here. */

#endif
```

In the first file, do:

```
#include "globals.h"
```

In the second file, do:

```
#include "globals.h"

/* rest of code here */

CLA *args = NULL;

/* more code here */
```